# How to remove timer lag in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using VB.Net to make a simple countdown timer however when comparing it with an actual countdown timer, the VB.Net one loses seconds. What can I do to prevent this?

```
'Variables used to countdown time
Dim HoursRemaining As Integer = 0
Dim MinsRemaining As Integer = 0
Dim SecondsRemaining As Integer = 0
'These are needed to get the time remaining into the format 00:00:00
Dim HoursStr As String
Dim MinsStr As String
Dim SecsStr As String

Private Sub TimeRemainingTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimeRemainingTimer.Tick
    If HoursRemaining = 0 And MinsRemaining = 0 And SecondsRemaining = 0 Then
        TimeRemaining.Text = "00:00:00"
        TimeRemainingTimer.Stop()
    End If

    If MinsRemaining = 0 And HoursRemaining > 0 Then
        MinsRemaining = 60
        HoursRemaining = HoursRemaining - 1
    End If
    If SecondsRemaining = 0 Then
        SecondsRemaining = 60
        MinsRemaining = MinsRemaining - 1
    End If

    SecondsRemaining = SecondsRemaining - 1
    TimeRemainingUpdate(SecondsRemaining)
End Sub

Private Sub TimeRemainingUpdate(ByVal SecondsRemaining As Integer)
    Do While eLength >= 60
        HoursRemaining = HoursRemaining + 1
        eLength = eLength - 60
    Loop

    If HoursRemaining Like "[0-9]" Then
        HoursStr = "0" & HoursRemaining
    Else
        HoursStr = HoursRemaining
    End If
    If MinsRemaining Like "[0-9]" Then
        MinsStr = "0" & MinsRemaining
    Else
        MinsStr = MinsRemaining
    End If
    If SecondsRemaining Like "[0-9]" Then
        SecsStr = "0" & SecondsRemaining
    Else
        SecsStr = SecondsRemaining
    End If

    TimeRemaining.Text = HoursStr & ":" & MinsStr & ":" & SecsStr
End Sub
```

Comment: You know we cannot see your code from here unless you actually post it, right?

Comment: Your code is way too complicated for something like this. Try using `division` and `mod`.

Comment: I would suggest using a `Timespan` and subtracting one second on every tick. That way you don't need all the seconds, minutes, hours logic

Comment: How would I use a "Timespan" ? @Kenneth

Comment: `Dim x as New TimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))` Then you could do something like `x.AddSeconds(-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the current system time on start and then use the difference between the current system time and the start system time to calculate what to show on the screen.

Comment: ... with the reason for that being that the timer will not necessarily tick exactly every 1000ms. Which suggests that an update check every, say, 100ms would be needed to avoid the chance of the seconds changing by 2 instead of 1 and also the jitter of the time of the display updates would not be visible.

Comment: This seems more logical than using a timespan

Comment: To avoid any skipping or inconsistency, set the timer to 16ms, that's slightly less than the refresh rate of a typical 60hz monitor (1000/60).

Comment: please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) `The Windows Forms Timer component ... is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds.` 16ms is gross overkill since the display is only seconds.

Comment: The margin of error on the current time will essentially be the duration of the timer. As the MSDN doc suggests, you can use the System.Timers.Timer instead, which you will need to use the Invoke method on your form so that the timer handler code to update the display is executed on the event thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but it would simplify your code a lot. Maybe that'll help you spot the error:

```
' Initialization
Dim counter as New TimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)) ' set your initial seconds here

Private Sub TimeRemainingTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimeRemainingTimer.Tick
    counter.AddSeconds(-1)
    TimeRemainingUpdate()
End Sub

Private Sub TimeRemainingUpdate()
    TimeRemaining.Text = counter.ToString("hh:mm:ss")  
End Sub
```

Inside the tick you'll have to do some checking on whether the TimeSpan has actually reached zero